# Automatically backup SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, sql-server-2005-express

I need to backup SQL Server database.

Is it possible to do this automatically without human intervention at regular intervals?  If so yes then  please suggest me how to do it and I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need this:

http://www.codeplex.com/ExpressMaint

Then you can create a .cmd file to run it and schedule it using Scheduled Tasks. I can't give you an exact command line because your setup will be different from mine, but the docs are here:

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=27

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=29

Answer (score 1):

There's a walkthrough on backing up SQL Server Express [here](http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/guestbloggers/archive/2007/05/07/how-to-automate-the-backup-of-a-sql-server-2005-express-data-store.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in sql 2005 scripts templates you will find backup script

from your code run this script in the time you want to backup your database

thats it i guess